# Want to downgrade from an Universal app to just an ipad app

Tags: ipad, universal-binary, project-settings, build-settings

I originally wanted to make a universal app, but now scopes have been changed and I am stuck with a universal app, now all I want is an iPad app. So I went and changed the Targeted Device Family to just 'iPad' (or 2) but when I submit the app it claims I am still stuck in Device Family '1,2' or Universal, and is asking for iPhone screen shots.

I have looked high and low to *downgrading from universal app to ipad*

No real results.

Also, it says minimum OS required 3.1.3, when I'd rather have it set to 3.2 (maybe this will solidify it's existence as an iPad only app).

Thank you in advance!

update:

I've added LSMinimumSystemVersion 3.2 to the info.plist (3.2 is a string)
 and under 'app Details' this makes me rage:

Minimum OS Requirements :       3.1.3

wut do. :(

update: contacted apple, they sent me to the Targeted Family Device telling me to 'make sure' then was forwarded to itunes connect support, then i had to write a few emails to dev support and itsconnect@apple.com, still circles.

my quest continues!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first make sure you change that setting both for the project and your target, if it is still unchanged just manually edit project.pbxproj in the xcode project bundle changing all occurences of TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = "1,2" to TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = "1"

also Minimum OS Requirements is determined by the deployment sdk setting (IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET in the aforementioned file) , not affected by LSMinimumSystemVersion

Comment: Seems to work, but we will see if they accept it. In xcode it limited each of my build settins to just 3.2 and ipad. And on iTunesconnect, it showed up family 2 and os 3.2. so yea very promising! 

THANK YOU!

Comment: The settings are totally valid and no reason for rejection, it is the same as changing values in Xcode only you done it manually.