# iPad only application

Tags: iphone

I want my universal application to be run only on iPad, (want to make it iPad only) what changes I have to do? Specifically, in Info.plist...

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 6):

Set 'Build Active Target Only' to true.

Set 'Target Family Device' to iPad.

**Update**

[Want to downgrade from an Universal app to just an ipad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277945/want-to-downgrade-from-an-universal-app-to-just-an-ipad-app)

[Submit an universal app as iPad only app to Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706215/submit-an-universal-app-as-ipad-only-app-to-apple)

Comment: Sorry man, I guess, I didnt get you properly, so if you tell me how can I degrade my universal app to iPad-only app then I will be glad.... :)

Comment: Go to Edit->Project Settings and find the Targeted Device Family. And pls see the links in my updated answer

Comment: Hello Dude, thanks for your help it seems to be work but I will more thankful to you if you will tell me, where I can get "Build Active Target Only" to check it, or what I got is "Build Active Architecture only".... so is it one the same with "Build Active Target only" as I am using XCode 3.2.5... :)

Comment: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/21/xcode-build-active-architecture-only.html will give you an idea of the settings